# Concrete bean could not be received from the application context with PF4J, PF4J-Spring and Wicket

Tags: spring, wicket, pf4j

I'm making a spring boot application using Wicket and PF4J. I want to use spring services in my plugins. These services are not using services outside the plugin class loader. In my plugin, I can have wicket panels. The panel class can use the Spring service.

Here the class of the plugin:

```
public class MyPlugin extends SpringPlugin implements MyPluginConfiguration {

    public MyPlugin(PluginWrapper wrapper) {
        super(wrapper);
    }

    @Override
    protected ApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.setClassLoader(getWrapper().getPluginClassLoader());
        applicationContext.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
        applicationContext.refresh();
        return applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Panel getConfigurationPanel(String wicketId) {
        return new ConfigurationPanel(wicketId);
    }

}
```

Its interface:

```
public interface MyPluginConfiguration {

    Panel getConfigurationPanel(String wicketId);
}
```

The SpringConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LabelService getLabelService() {
        return new LabelService();
    }
}
```

The configuration panel:

```
public class ConfigurationPanel extends Panel {

    @SpringBean
    private LabelService labelService;

    public ConfigurationPanel(String id) {
        super(id);

        add(new Label("text", labelService.getLabel()));
    }

}
```

And the service:

```
@Service
public class LabelService {

    public String getLabel() {
        return "Hello World from the plugin.";
    }
}
```

To display the configuration, i'm using this page in my application:

```
public class PluginTestPage extends WebPage {

    @SpringBean
    private PluginManager pluginManager;

    public PluginTestPage() {
        final PluginWrapper pluginWrapper = pluginManager.getPlugin("example");
        if (pluginWrapper.getPlugin() instanceof MyPluginConfiguration) {
            final MyPluginConfiguration pluginConfiguration = (MyPluginConfiguration) pluginWrapper.getPlugin();
            add(pluginConfiguration.getConfigurationPanel("configuration-panel"));
        } else {
            add(new Label("configuration-panel", "Can't get the configuration panel"));
        }
    }

}
```

When I'm asking the PluginTestPage, I have this error:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public com.example.pages.PluginTestPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:90) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider$Provision.getPage(PageProvider.java:369) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:170) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:231) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:202) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:917) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:63) ~[wicket-request-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:254) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:222) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:276) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:207) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:300) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concrete bean could not be received from the application context for class: com.example.pf4j_wicket_spring.services.LabelService.
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringBeanLocator.lookupSpringBean(SpringBeanLocator.java:277) ~[wicket-spring-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringBeanLocator.locateProxyTarget(SpringBeanLocator.java:198) ~[wicket-spring-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:150) ~[wicket-spring-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:111) ~[wicket-ioc-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.inject(SpringComponentInjector.java:124) ~[wicket-spring-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.onInstantiation(SpringComponentInjector.java:130) ~[wicket-spring-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:38) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:34) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80) ~[wicket-util-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.onInstantiation(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:33) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.<init>(Component.java:682) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.<init>(MarkupContainer.java:185) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer.<init>(WebMarkupContainer.java:53) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer.<init>(WebMarkupContainer.java:45) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel.<init>(Panel.java:67) ~[wicket-core-9.0.0.jar:9.0.0]
    at com.example.pf4j_wicket_spring.panels.ConfigurationPanel.<init>(ConfigurationPanel.java:25) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.pf4j_wicket_spring.MyPlugin.getConfigurationPanel(MyPlugin.java:40) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.pages.PluginTestPage.<init>(PluginTestPage.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

What is the origin of the problem ? Is it a mistake with my settings or a bug with pf4j-spring ?

Regards,
Stef

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the stacktrace Wicket is not aware of the Spring configuration.

Wicket does not known about PF4J and its Spring integration.

You need to configure Wicket to use SpringConfiguration too.